# Backdrop disappear all my modal on click - bootstrap Twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Regards,

Reading the modal options of bootstrap of twitter. There is a option that preventing my modal closing when clicking outside the modal or in div.modal-backdrop.

The backdrop option is: false. However, I realized that this div contains the black background and if I change to FALSE removes the background. My question is, I can keep the background backdrop disappear , if I put this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood but, if I did, I think it's related to this: "Alternatively, specify static for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click."
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Sorry if I got it wrong...

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution with the options of the Modal.